# I need to pass vue data into PHP

Tags: php, sql, vue.js, axios

SQL query is not running though the variable value is showing on the screen if echo $eventID is used. I am using Vue and Axios

I have used 1 manually and then the code runs perfectly. But this way the application will not be dynamic

```
$var = '{{ upcomingEvent.eventID }}';
                $eventId =  $var;
                // echo $eventId;
                $user = $_SESSION["customer_email"];
                $sql = "select * from liked where event = '$eventId' AND 
user = '$user'";
                $result = $conn->query($sql);
                if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                    // echo $eventId;
                    echo '<i class="fas fa-thumbs-up fa-3x" 
@click="dislikeEvent(upcomingEvent);"></i>';
                } else {
                    // echo $user;
                    echo '<i class="far fa-thumbs-up fa-3x" 
@click="likeEvent(upcomingEvent);"></i>';
                }
```

The code should be able to find whether the user have liked the event or not

Comment: This is just a side project. I am not concerned about PHP security. I am learning vue and want to know how I can run the sql query. I can later concentrate on PHP security in this project once I understand Vue properly.